# How to convert speech to text? Windows 8 RT

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, windows-rt

Is it possible to convert speech to text without using a web service? I have tried the following solution but the libraries aren't recognised in eclipse,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207021(v=vs.105).aspx

I'm thinking there has to be a speech recognition API in Windows 8 RT? Does anyone have an implementation of speech recognition in this platform or point me in the right direction?

I'm guessing that these methods are not available on the Windows 8 RT platform,If so are there any alternatives?

I tried the following in an app bar button click event but none of the methods/namespaces are recognized.

```
            // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizerUI.
            this.recoWithUI = new SpeechRecognizerUI();

            // Start recognition (load the dictation grammar by default).
            SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

            // Do something with the recognition result.
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You said {0}.", recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `SpeechRecognitionUI` class is for Windows Phone 8.

For Windows 8 RT, Microsoft has the [The Bing Speech Recognition Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434583.aspx) and [the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434633.aspx) is called `SpeechRecognizerUx`.

> The Bing Speech Recognition Control enables a `Windows 8`, `Windows 8.1`,
>   or `Windows RT` machine to **convert audio speech input to written text**.
>   It does this by receiving audio data from a microphone, sending the
>   audio data to a web service for analysis, and then returning its best
>   interpretations of user speech as text.

The one 'caveat' (if you don't wanna pay) is that this [requires a subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434606.aspx) to Windows Azure Data Marketplace, although the free stuff is pretty generous IMO.

> The Bing Speech Recognition Control is only available from the Visual
>   Studio Gallery. To develop with the Bing Speech Recognition Control,
>   you must first subscribe on the Windows Azure Data Marketplace, and
>   then register your application. There is no cost to subscribe for the
>   first 500,000 service calls per month.

Here's a code sample.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

SpeechRecognizer SR;
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Apply credentials from the Windows Azure Data Marketplace.
    var credentials = new SpeechAuthorizationParameters();
    credentials.ClientId = "<YOUR CLIENT ID>";
    credentials.ClientSecret = "<YOUR CLIENT SECRET>";

    // Initialize the speech recognizer and attach to control.
    SR = new SpeechRecognizer("en-US", credentials);
    SpeechControl.SpeechRecognizer = SR;
}

private async void SpeakButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Start speech recognition.
        var result = await SR.RecognizeSpeechToTextAsync();
        ResultText.Text = result.Text;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        ResultText.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

**Source:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434633.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4

Comment: Updated. The same MSDN link has it. Note the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` which are your credentials for the Azure Data Marketplace (the caveat i mentioned).

Comment: I'm wondering how I stop the service when I'm finshed taking notes.I'm guessing I would have to have a stop button click event that would call stop on the service? Or would there be a better way to stop it without a button?

Comment: I think the session automatically stops / ends after a certain number of seconds of silence? Not sure. Take a look at the `SpeechRecognizer.AudioCaptureStateChanged` event and the `SpeechRecognizer.RequestCancelOperation()` method. The former taps into the various states of the speech recognition, and the latter allows you to force cancel a current speech recording session. Between the two, you should be able to fine tune your service. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434572.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn434585.aspx

Comment: Seems that this API isn't available in Ireland.....Any other alternatives out there for achieving this?